# Добавить тип документа при записи в файл

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста понять как можно добавлять тип xml-документа при записи

например, есть следующий код, записывающий xml-дерево в файл

```
def record_xml(xml, fileName='xml.xml'):
    try:
        with open(fileName, "w") as file:
            file.write(xml)
    except Exception:
        print('Error record', Exception)
    else:
        print('record ok')
        return True

record_xml(xmlPretty)
```

в результате в файл записываются только xml-тэги:

```
<data>
  <item>
    <message>что с браузером</message>
    <section>Взаимопомощь</section>
    <date>05.07.2013</date>
  </item>
...............
.....
```

а мне нужно чтобы перед всеми тэгами была строчка:

> <*?_xml version="1.0"
> encoding="utf-8"?*>

вот это работало бы в python2, но не работает в python3:

```
xmlPretty = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Как `tree.tostring()` так и `tree.write()` методы работают:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from lxml import etree # $ pip install lxml

xml = r'''<data>
  <item>
    <message>что с браузером</message>
    <section>Взаимопомощь</section>
    <date>05.07.2013</date>
  </item></data>'''.encode('utf-8')

tree = etree.fromstring(xml).getroottree() # or etree.parse(file)
tree.write(sys.stdout.buffer, # or tree.write(file, # binary file: 'wb'
           xml_declaration=True, encoding=tree.docinfo.encoding)
```

Вывод:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
  <item>
    <message>что с браузером</message>
    <section>Взаимопомощь</section>
    <date>05.07.2013</date>
  </item></data>
```

`file` должен быть открыт в бинарном режиме: `open(filename, "wb")` в обоих случаях.